# Sort everything after id

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have an MongoDB-Table with lets say a billion entrys. Every Entry has an numeric index which is set to auto_increment.
One day i decide to delete some entrys in the middle of the database (See _id: 18).

```
{ "_id" : 16, "email" : "LcZL4E43gd", "password" : "test", "lastseen" : 1548354920 }
{ "_id" : 17, "email" : "YQo4SKEslh", "password" : "test", "lastseen" : 1548354920 }
{ "_id" : 19, "email" : "tVlsT6yZxv", "password" : "test", "lastseen" : 1548354920 }
{ "_id" : 20, "email" : "xoMF4dt2Fn", "password" : "test", "lastseen" : 1548354920 }
```

So now the counter goes 16, 17, 19, 20. But my Code needs to stop at an empty failed get request. So it would stop in the middle of the Table, because an index is missing.
How do i effectively update every _id element to match the upcounting auto_increment index?
Is there an predefined method i dont know of?

Comment: There's a chance people will react negatively to this, but here you go: answer is in front of you - do not delete records, add new field `deleted` to mark record as deleted. I never, never delete records, and I'm happy. Be like me.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs: In this case, you should also overwrite any data associated with this key. Otherwise, data of deleted users can be read - I wouldn't want any site to still have my data in the database after I deleted my account.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs by Law in Germany, if a user decides to want all his data deleted from your website you NEED to do that. There is no excuse made by Law Enforcement, you're required to delete every information you have from that user.

Comment: That is absolutely true - that's an outcome of a special case about wiping data like GPDR, but still record itself can be kept. The point of keeping all deleted records helps a lot in case of problem solving, and can save you lots of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do i effectively update every _id element to match the upcounting auto_increment index?**

> You cannot. '_id' field is immutable in MongoDB. Once a value has been
>   assigned to it, you cannot change it.
>
> If you really want to do something like that (which you should not),
>   first, you need to move your sequential counter to a different field
>   (not _id). But, do remember that, as you have mentioned if you have
>   one billion documents and your 18th document is deleted, do you want
>   all the rest of the documents (1 billion - 18 !!!!!) to be updated?

**Suggestion:**
Better to redefine your API to accept 'holes' in your sequences (like if 18 doesn't exist, move on). But, without knowing the entire application scenario, it is difficult for anyone to suggest it.

More Information on `_id` field can be obtained here:
https://www.vividcortex.com/blog/what-is-mongodbs-_id-field-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: Ok, i undestand, thank you.   I'll just make an emty Object out of it and overwrite the emty Object if somebody new comes in.